# PHP + SQL Server, SQL works but RESET flag being set in server response

Tags: php, sql-server, apache, pdo, sqlsrv

I'm experiencing odd behavior when working with PHP and the PDO extension for SQL Server, on a Windows machine with an Apache web server. I added the necessary .dlls to /php/ext to enable the extensions, and phpinfo shows that sqlsrv has been installed/loaded. I also installed the SQL Server native client. However when accessing a page that simply connects to a SQL Server database and executes a simple INSERT query, the web server responds with the error `ERR_CONNECTION_RESET`. I checked the packet and the Reset flag is being set; I also checked the database and the INSERT query actually does successfully execute, with new rows being added, but the web server is for some reason setting the Reset flag. Does anyone know what's going on here?

Edit: It seems as though INSERT or UPDATE statements work, but SELECT statements cause the `ERR_CONNECTION_RESET` flag.

There is no antivirus running and no proxies, and the page loads without the `ERR_CONNECTION_RESET` if the code that makes the INSERT query is commented out.

For what it's worth, here's the code:

```
// This does not cause the ERR_CONNECTION_RESET error
$pdo = new PDO('sqlsrv:Server=' . $host . ';Database=' . $database, $user, $pass);
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO Table1 (Col1, Col2) VALUES ('test', 4)");
$stmt->execute();

// This causes the ERR_CONNECTION_RESET error
$pdo = new PDO('sqlsrv:Server=' . $host . ';Database=' . $database, $user, $pass);
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT Col1, Col2 FROM Table1");
$stmt->execute();
$data = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Comment: If you *don't* do the query, do you still see the `ERR_CONNECTION_RESET`? Do you see anything in the PHP error log? Can you simplify your code to a reproducing case that we can see?

Comment: Right, if I don't execute the query, that error does not occur. If I comment out the portion of SQL the page renders. The exact code works on a different computer so the SQL isn't an issue.

Comment: And if you have PHP error reporting turned on, or look in your error logs?

Comment: PHP error reporting is turned on (the PDO code is actually wrapped in a try/catch, as well). The INSERT statement works, I can see the table get new rows. It looks like a network issue, regarding traffic (the data in the SELECT query) coming from the SQL Server

Comment: So if you don't execute any code *after* the `fetchAll`, you get the same error? And the `execute()` definitely doesn't return `false`?

Comment: The only code after fetchAll() is `die('test');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered the problem. After checking the Windows Event Log, I noticed some entries associated with the Apache executable. Looking in these entries, the php .dll was flagged as a fault module. I replaced that with the .dll that worked on a different computer, and I am no longer experiencing this error.

**A faulty PHP .dll caused the Apache server to crash, resulting in the server error.**

Answer (score 0):

"Reformed" answer rocks and got me 90% of the way to a solution.  The last 10% involved a different dll.

I have Apache 2.4 and PHP 5.5 running on Windows 10 for a Dev system.  The complaint I was getting in the Event log concerned the "sqlncli10.dll" file.  Googling "apache connection reset sqlncli10.dll" led to this web resource: [Rob's Area for PHP on Windows](http://robsphp.blogspot.com/2012/06/unofficial-microsoft-sql-server-driver.html).  On it was a link to a OneDrive public file: [MS OneDrive Folder of SQL drivers for PHP](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=669EE24817961774%21720).

I installed the MSI found there (after scanning the heck out of it for malware, etc) and it quite cured the Connection Reset issue for me.